# How to read application.properties in utils class

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am writing a REST service using Spring Boot.

Method in my rest service calls a util class and this util class needs to refer certain properties defined in the application.properties

I user @Value and it didnt work inside the util class, where as it works in my REST service class.

My REST service: ReportsController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ReportsController{

    @Value("${report.path}")
    private String reportPath;

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String retrieveWelcomeMessage() {
        return new ExcelFileUtil().test();
    }
    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/welcome1")
    public String retrieveWelcomeMessage() {
        return reportPath;
    }
}
```

My Utils class: MyUtil.java

```
 public class  MyUtil{

     @Value("${report.path}")
     private String reportPath;

    public String test()
     {
         return reportPath;
     } 
 }
```

I am getting the value from application.properties is printed for http://localhost:8080/api/v1/welcome1
But getting blank for http://localhost:8080/api/v1/welcome

How to make the application.properties readable inside the MyUtil.java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your Util class as a component of spring. @Value will work only on spring managed dependencies

```
@Component
public class  MyUtil{

 @Value("${report.path}")
 private String reportPath;

 public String test(){
     return reportPath;
 } 
}
```

Make sure the package of MyUtil is added to component-scan

..and use the MyUtil as a Autowired dependency whereever you want to use like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ReportsController{

@Autowired
private MyUtil myUtil;

public void someMethod() {
   myUtil.reportPath();
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you Jayesh. I tried @Component, but never worked. This time it works with Autowired

Comment: Jayesh, but what about testing? How we can test util class?

Comment: it’s straightforward as writing any spring test. use @Runwith(SpringJunitTestTunner) or use @springboottest. you can find a lot of examples