# Why I cannot use @Value in utility class

Tags: java, spring

These are my utility class and controller class respectively.

```
@UtilityClass
public class MyUtil {

    @Value("${myvalue}")
    private String testString;

    public String test(){
        return testString;
    }
}
```

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String gethello(){
        return MyUtil.test();
    }
```

It returns the null value.
I fix the issue by following [How to read application.properties in utils class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087746/how-to-read-application-properties-in-utils-class)
But my question is that why the original approach doesn't work. I just want a reference from the properties file so that I can easily define the parameters. Many thanks.

Comment: Show how you are initializing `myUtil`.

Comment: It is a static class after adding @UtilityClass

Comment: I don't need to initialize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring doesn't support `@Value` on static fields. Given the lombok `@UtilityClass` annotation makes all members static, this won't work.

Comment: Then which one you think is a better approach?

Comment: It depends on the context, you can use `@Value`  to inject individual properties into your controller.  If you want to inject lots of properties you can [write a class with](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) `@ConfigurationProperties` as per the linked example and inject that into your controller.

Comment: It's also a valid solution to turn your utility class into a spring component and inject it. Spring components are singletons by default so making it a component means you will reference the same utility class instance event if you use it in multiple controllers and or other components.